# Laravel sendmail driver

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm having problems with the driver as it sends mail when I'm in my company, but once I come home with the same machine it doesn't do anything. Seems as it is storing it somewhere because when I get back to work I get all the mails I used to test when I was home.

My `.env` is set to a sendmail driver:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

And I am sending a mail like this

```
Mail::to($data['user']['email'], $data['user']['name'])->send(new Confirmation($data['user']));
```

Everything seems to work when I'm at my workplace so I suppose there is some config file to set up which I don't know about that doesn't allow doing it from my IP?

Comment: have you fired `php artisan config:cache`?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP has probably blocked `port 25` because of how easily (in the past) computers were infected and abused.

Instead, you should use encryption and port `465` which has been the defacto recommendation for awhile.

Comment: But how can I do that with sendmail driver?

Comment: @Norgul Short of calling your ISP and asking them to open port 25 for you, you won't. You'll need to use an email account and `smtp` to send the mail.